# Woman touch Buddha

Tags: meditation, buddha, tipitaka, wheel-of-dhamma

q:

> Can a woman touch a Buddha? And if so, what would happen, how would
>   the Buddha react?

Comment: Haven't you read/heard about story between Buddha and brahmin of kuru pradesh(of ancient India) ,who wanted buddha to marry his beautiful daughter.

Comment: Yes, if that woman touch Lord Buddha with good intention, she accumulates good kamma and if that woman touch Lord Buddha with bad intention, she accumulates bad kamma. Since Lord Buddha has no defilements, there would be no reaction.

Answer (score 1):

No one can touch the Buddha, Tatagatha, good householder, if not gained Arahat-ship, or at least the Dhamma temporary by oneselves, not even see.

If a woman touches, was able to touch the Buddha, she is called a Arahat, or at least Noble One, if just temporary.

*(Note: This is not given for stackes, exchange, other trades, binding in the world, but to escape from this wheel)*

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would happen to buddha, as he has understood the reality of this world, in other words as he has realized the four noble truth. Buddha will just pay sad for this woman as she is blinded with klesha in her mind.

But for that woman, she will get bad karma if she does it with bad thoughts (ragha, dwesha, moha).

Answer (score 0):

Any one can touch buddha but there is **nothing happening special**.

Buddha haven't "**Keles**" means

No attraction 
No feeling (sad love ext)
No any impression only patient

meaning is likely can our|you mind mix with Water or any material.this is only simple description .and what are you asking is very deep but simply buddha is treat all living thins same.no any touch only patient